# How do I troubleshoot a P1443 code for a Chevy Equinox

Tags: fuel-system, chevrolet, equinox

I have a 2012 Chevy Equinox LT that started reporting code p1443, and has started to die from time to time. This happens when the Equinox is at rest, either in gear or in "Park," then begins moving in either Drive or Reverse. The engine makes no sounds when it dies, it just dies as smoothly as if I turned the engine off myself. The engine will rev up to 3k-4k RPM while in Park without issue.

A few good revs and the problem temporarily goes away. I've replaced the evap purge solenoid so far, but it didn't fix the issue.

How should I go about troubleshooting the problem?

Comment: When you say it is "at rest" and then dies, do you mean you have it in gear all the time and when you go to take off it dies, or that as you put it in gear it dies? The P1443 could also pertain to a gas cap which is leaking air or not sealed correctly, or it could be a bad hose going to your evap system.

Comment: It occurs in both cases - at rest while in gear at a light, or when taking off after changing from Park to Drive or Reverse. Reving the engine to between 3k and 4k RPM while in Park is fine, however.

Comment: In other words, when you ease into the pedal to go, it dies?

Comment: Correct, although easing into the pedal VERY gradually is sometimes OK.

Comment: could it be the fuel filter? Mine is doing the same thing and it jerks really hard going down the road just not all the time. but when i stop at stop lights it dies and starts back just fine does it three or four times and then its ok. the engine light keeps coming on and going off. it's alot worse when im a quarter of a tank of gas or less

Comment: It ended up being the intake and exhaust actuator solenoids - I ended up having to take it to the shop where they could plug it into a more advanced scanner that could report multiple error codes.

Answer (score 2):

From your description and comments, I'd suggest you have a dead spot in your Throttle Position Sensor (TPS) right after idle (low end of the throttle). If the TPS is not reporting the correct throttle position, the computer will not lengthen the pulse width of the injector to give the engine more gas, which will in turn cause the engine to die. If you get the engine above this spot, it will rev fairly high and run at the higher RPM. This is just a theory, but should give you somewhere to start.

Comment: Awesome, would you recommend I just replace it or try to clean it and the throttle body using the method described in this article? http://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicAdvice/comments/2sr8pw/2011_chevrolet_equinox_lt_throttle_position/cnsajg9

Comment: Start by getting it tested. The TPS is just my theory, but it is a good place to start your troubleshooting, as you've asked. If this doesn't pan out, we can probably help you take another route before you start replacing parts.

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be able to tell me what the p1443 code on a GM means, would you? Also the throttle problem seems to have gone away for the moment.